# Application hanging when the WCF client communicating with the server

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-ria-services

I am a beginner with WCF. When I am running the application, it works, but while the client communicates with the server, the application hangs and I can't do anything in the application while it starts communicating. Can you suggest some ideas to rectify this?

Comment: Can you please post some client code? Do you use an extra thread when calling WCF?

Comment: use thread and run it in background

Comment: @BrijeshMishra is absolutely correct. Never do any network calls on your main thread.

Comment: still now we are not using threads. can u explain me how to use threads in wcf application?

Answer (score 0):

Setup an own thread to do the WCF call, one possibility is to use the Thread class, see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx

Please note that you have to take special precautions if you process/display result coming back from a WCF call, because this will then be outside of your main UI thread (if you do not use a SynchronizationContext etc...)

Answer (score 0):

The WCF Data Services client API has built in methods to call WCF Data Services asynchronously: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756365.aspx